# gtmetrix and pagespeed low score

Tags: joomla-3.x, performance

I am using Joomla 3.3 and JA Teline IV template. My sites gtmetrix is very low.

Here are my settings:

Joomla Cache ON
Cache Plugin Enabled
SEF Enabled

JCH Optimize Plugin

Combine CSS files Yes
Combine JavaScript Files Yes
Gzip Javascript and CSS Yes
Minify Yes
Minify JavaScript NO (I think it will also minify my adsense code so dont want to take chance to get banned from adense)
Minify HTML Yes
Defer JavaScript (I also think deferring Javascript will cause my adsense banned)

Menu item Home
Exclude all extension Yes
Exclude CSS files - ja.tabs.css (but it is still showing in rendering block) not excluding at all
Exclude JavaScript same as above - Ja.tabs.js

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.livemedia24.com/3gHbCdCZ

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2F&tab=desktop

Please see above reports and help. I also dont want to Leverage browser cache as i am updating my website daily basis, well i am newbie in this so dont have clear idea about it. Your suggestion comments will be appreciated.

I also did some settings in my K2, Image quality 100% to 80%. I am not sure if K2 is working fine on images are not.

Comment: I would agree it seems to be being tough on you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first report states:

> **Understand the recommendations**
>
> They are meant to be generic, best practices; not everything will apply to your site.
>
> **Rules are sorted in order of impact upon score**
>
> Optimizing rules at the top of the list can greatly improve your overall score.

My experience has been that these types of reports almost always make good recommendations, but the effort to implement the fix personally outweighs the benefit, so you have to think about your own needs and fix your problems over blindly following a generic report like this.

So let's tackle some of my thoughts on the items:

---

**Defer parsing of JavaScript**

This is a good idea. But you're not going to implement this in Joomla.

To do this would require rewriting a lot of core code. Should that be done, maybe. Either way, I would highly doubt that anyone reading this answer will do it for their own site, so you can effectively ignore it.

**Serve scaled images**

You can manually scale images yourself if you only need them at a smaller size, but I'm not aware of any core way to get resized images at this time. There may be an extension to help with this, but it will likely have quirks. I would recommend looking in to this, since this can definitely increase the page load time and make your site more mobile friendly.

**Specify image dimensions**

This could also probably help, but I've never seen it have a big effect.

**Leverage browser caching**

This is a good idea, but is a server configuration for the most part, so it happens outside of Joomla. Ideally, you at least want the browser to be able to cache images, scripts, and stylesheets. These really don't change that often (or if they do, you should rename them or add a `?v=**timestamp**` ending to break the cache. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

This site explains how to adjust your .htaccess file to enable caching by extension: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-speed.htm. (Note: whether this actually works is dependent on your host.)

**Enable gzip compression**

You can do this in the Joomla Global Configuration if you like.

---

### What isn't mentioned in that report

I can see in that report that your site took 7.15s to load. That is obviously WAY too slow, hence why you went and ran this report.

What this report can't tell you is what could be holding up your site in delivering the initial file. I ran a waterfall speed test at http://tools.pingdom.com. This doesn't seem to affect your site (initial response was sub 1 second), so you really need to focus on resizing images (and maybe consider having less images or adding more images through ajax so it doesn't slow initial page load).

For others that may look at this answer, I highly recommend using Joomla's debug mode (in global config) to get a list of queries run on a particular page load. This will give you the time that each query took. Optimizing queries is always my first stop in speeding up a site.

Comment: I'd agree too with your first comments, these things can make your site faster, but if they take too much time or not possible for you, they only matter if you get reports from your visitors that they are effecting them.

Answer (score 2):

I Would say you could make some of you images smaller:
http://www.livemedia24.com/media/k2/items/cache/32e0741e68cabc7552333046597de1b4_XL.jpg
Is 247KB but it is not massive, it just should have a intro image size for the homepage.

With T3 you some times have to be careful about combining css and js as they are generated from scripts not flat css or js. As you have said you have turned on compressing and pulling together css and js but these dont seem to have happen when you look at the live html. There are lots of calls, and to jatabs ones too. So maybe these are hard coded into your template and not in the joomla functions that JCH compresses.

You could turn on gzip compression in the general joomla settings. Which would effect the html, css, js etc

So I would say it looks like your site output html looks well formed but it is not working with JCH to optimise it for you so look at the template code if you can?